# I can't type the letter "e" in the python3 shell

Tags: python

This is a weird one. Whenever I enter the python3 shell (doesn't happen in python [2]) and type "e" it immediately replaces that character with "HI THERE". For example, if I try to type "exit()" it turns into "HI THERExit()".

Here's what happens when I type `python3<CR>exit()` in my default shell (zsh).

```
% python3
>>> HI THERExit()
```

And I just discovered this same behavior happens when I invoke the bash shell.

```
% bash
bash-3.2$ HI THERExit
```

I have no idea where the problem could be. Bash/zsh settings? Vim command mode remap? Some kind of python3 alias or auto expansion? Please give me some places to check, or a strategy to find it (e.g. grep folder XYZ). A "HI THERE" test string seems like something I would have set up at some point but I have no recollection of it.

Comment: Individual key replacement sounds like a keyboard macro, not anything to do with shell or Python.  But you say it happens only in Python 3, and not Python 2?

Comment: You don't have a programmable keyboard do you?

Comment: Definitely not a programming topic in the sense of Stack Overflow.

Comment: does it also happen on `python -c exit()<CR>`? Also do you have AHK or autoit?

Comment: @JohnGordon Correct, it does not happen in python (2). As far as I know just python3 and bash.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's the builtin Macbook keyboard.

Comment: @Finn I got a parse error on that `zsh: parse error near \`\n'` but I tried `python -c 'exit()'` and `python3 -c 'exit()'` and got no error. I don't think I have AHK or autoit.

Comment: What's in your `~/.pythonrc.py` file? I realize the issue affects Bash too, but maybe it's been separately set up for Python and Bash. Obviously you've been pranked by someone, just need to figure out how they did it.

Comment: You probably have something defined in `.inputrc`, which configures the Readline library. `bash` uses Readline, and Python *can* use it. (For instance, my Homebrew(?)-installed Python 2 does not, but the system Python 2 does.)

Comment: Try looking in System Preferences > Keyboard, and see if you have configured replacement text for the `e` key.

Comment: `.inputrc` might contain something like `"e": "Exit()"`.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I don't have a pythonrc. Pretty sure I was the one who did the accidental pranking. I just need to figure out how.

Comment: OH MY GOD @chepner the first line of my inputrc is `echo "HI THERE"`. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot which part was the replacement text :)

Comment: I disagree with the close reason on this question.  Questions about programming environments are on topic, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to all who offered ideas. And a big thanks to @chepner who suggested ~/.inputrc, the first line of which was `echo "HI THERE"`. Case closed.

Comment: For future reference, keep in mind that `.inputrc` is not a shell script; it's an initialization file for the Readline library. I can't find this documented, but it seems that `<key> <text>` is the same as `<key>: <text>`, and only the `e` of `echo` is considered the key to bind. The rest up to the first space, `cho`, is apparently just ignored.

Comment: My guess is that you edited that file thinking that you were updating your shell startup script or something, and you printed "HI THERE" to see if it was actually being executed. Of course it wasn't, but you didn't revert your change and only noticed it when you started running commands that use readline. If are using Time Machine, you could use it to determine when you made the edit.